# DataFrame add boolean column by checking multiple parameters

Tags: pandas, dataframe, boolean, ipython

I am looking for something like this.

```
tweets = pd.DataFrame()

tweets['worldwide'] = [tweets['user.location'] == ["Worldwide", "worldwide", "WorldWide]]
```

The new column 'worldwide' has boolean values (True, False) by checking column tweets['user.location'] which has three different types of spellings of worldwide.

I want that value "True" should be returned for all the tree formats of spelling "worldwide".

Answer (score 1):

IIUC then you want [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin):

```
tweets['worldwide'] = [tweets['user.location'].isin(["Worldwide", "worldwide", "WorldWide"])]
```

This will return `True` if any of the values are present

```
In [229]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tweets':['worldwide', 'asdas', 'Worldwide', 'WorldWide']})
df

Out[229]:
      Tweets
0  worldwide
1      asdas
2  Worldwide
3  WorldWide

In [230]:
df['Worldwide'] = df['Tweets'].isin(["Worldwide", "worldwide", "WorldWide"])
df

Out[230]:
      Tweets Worldwide
0  worldwide      True
1      asdas     False
2  Worldwide      True
3  WorldWide      True
```

However, I personally think there is more mileage in normalising the tweets so you compare to a single representation by lowercasing the tweets using [`str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html#pandas.Series.str.lower) and then use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) to test if the tweets contain your word:

```
In [231]:
df['Worldwide'] = df['Tweets'].str.lower().str.contains("worldwide")
df

Out[231]:
      Tweets Worldwide
0  worldwide      True
1      asdas     False
2  Worldwide      True
3  WorldWide      True
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this as final form:
          `tweets['worldwide'] = tweets['user.location'].str.lower().str.contains("worldwide")`

and the final count emerged as:

```
tweets['worldwide'].value_counts()


False    4998
 True      185
 Name: worldwide, dtype: int64
```